# Access objects from another module

Tags: python, object, scope

I'm a very inexperienced programmer creating a game (using Python 3.3) as a learning exercise. I currently have a main module and a combat module.

The people in the game are represented by instances of class "Person", and are created in the main module. However, the combat module obviously needs access to those objects. Furthermore, I'm probably going to create more modules later that will also need access to those objects.

How do I allow other modules to access the Persons from main.py?

As things stand, main.py has

```
import combat
```

at the top; adding

```
import main
```

to combat.py doesn't seem to help.

Should I instantiate my objects in a separate module (common.py?) and import them to every module that needs to access them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you should factor this out. What you tried is circular imports between your modules, and that typically causes more problems than it solves. If `combat` imports `main` and `main` imports `combat`, then you may get an error because some object definitions will be missing from `main` when you try to import them. This is because `main` will not have finished executing when `combat` starts executing for the import. Assuming `main` is your start up script, it should do nothing more than start the program by calling a method from another module; it may instantiate an object if the desired method is an instance method on a class. Avoid global variables, too. Even if it doesn't seem like they'll be a problem now, that can bite you later on.

That said, you can reference members of a module like so:

```
import common
x = common.some_method_in_common()
y = common.SomeClass()
```

or

```
from common import SomeClass
y = SomeClass()
```

Personally, I generally avoid referencing a method from another module without qualifying it with the module name, but this is also legal:

```
from common import some_method_in_common
x = some_method_in_common()
```

I typically use `from ... import ...` for classes, and I typically use the first form for methods. (Yes, this sometimes means I have specific class imports from a module in addition to importing the module itself.) But this is only my personal convention.

An alternate syntax of which is [*strongly* discouraged](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#imports) is

```
from common import *
y = SomeClass()
```

This will import every member of common into the current scope that does not start with an underscore (`_`). The reason it's discouraged is because it makes identifying the source of the name harder and it makes breaking things too easy. Consider this pair of imports:

```
from common import *
from some_other_module import *
y = SomeClass()
```

Which module does `SomeClass` come from? There's no way to tell other than to go look at the two modules. Worse, what if **both** modules define `SomeClass` or `SomeClass` is later added to `some_other_module`?

Comment: You're welcome. If an answer offered by someone answers you question, you can mark it as an answer by clicking the check mark below the up/down vote buttons.

Answer (score 2):

if you have imported main module in `combat` module by using `import main`, then you should use main.*(stuff that are implemented in main module) to access classes and methods in there.

example:

```
import main

person = main.Person()
```

also you can use `from main import *` or `import Person` to avoid main.* in the previous.

There are some rules for importing modules as described in http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm :

1. `import X` imports the module X, and creates a reference to that
   module in the current namespace. Or in other words, after you’ve run
   this statement, you can use `X.name` to refer to things defined in
   module X.
2. `from X import *` imports the module X, and creates references in
   the current namespace to all public objects defined by that module
   (that is, everything that doesn’t have a name starting with “_”). Or
   in other words, after you’ve run this statement, you can simply use
   a plain name to refer to things defined in module X. But X itself is
   not defined, so `X.name` doesn’t work. And if name was already
   defined, it is replaced by the new version. And if name in X is
   changed to point to some other object, your module won’t notice.
3. `from X import a, b, c` imports the module X, and creates references
   in the current namespace to the given objects. Or in other words,
   you can now use `a` and `b` and `c` in your program.
4. Finally, `X = __import__(‘X’)` works like `import X`, with the
   difference that you

   1) pass the module name as a string, and

   2) explicitly assign it to a variable in your current namespace.

Comment: D'oh! I forgot about this. Silly mistake.

Comment: Please do not suggest `from X import *`