# Python: how to access already instantiated class object in PyQt?

Tags: python, oop, scope, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a simple subclass of a base class, QLineEdit, which is just an editable text box from PyQt5:

```
class pQLineEdit(QtWidgets.QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self,parent)

    def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self,e):
        self.setText("Test")
```

This class works fine. The object's text is indeed updated when I double  click it.

However, at this event, I am in need of accessing an object, foo.bar,  from another, already-instantiated class in another file. How can I do this? I have tried

```
import other_file
...
def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self,e):
  self.setText("Test")
  foo.bar
```

I get:

```
 NameError: global name 'foo' is not defined
```

I've tried hacking my way just using

```
eval("foo.bar")
```

But it complains foo.bar is not defined. I feel this is very simple but the answer eludes me.

I should clarify: foo() is a class instantiated in a FUNCTION in the other file, which is main(). I must access the instantiated class because it contains an SSH tunnel. I don't think my question is a dupe as listed.

Comment: You need to be more specific about what that other object and what module it's in.  You need to store that object somewhere where your event handler can access it.  That may require importing the module containing `foo.bar` from the module containing your handler.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a pyqt question, but a dupe of a very basic python question that is already answered here. For instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15168024/python-access-objects-from-another-module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the risk of stating the obvious: if you want to access a variable, you need to put it somewhere that is accessible. The local scope of a function is not accessible to any code outside of that function.

To make a variable accessible to another module, it must be assigned in the global scope, or be assigned as an attribute of another object that is in the global scope.

If the variable cannot be assigned when the module is loaded, define it using the `global` statement:

```
foo = None

def main():
    global foo
    foo = MyClass()
    ...
```

However, a more appropriate approach for a gui application would be for the top-level window to provide access to the variable:

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.foo = MyClass()
```

Any child widget that has the main window as its parent can then access the variable via its `parent()` method:

```
class LineEdit(QtWidgets.QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(LineEdit, self).__init__(parent)

    def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, event):
        bar = self.parent().foo.bar
```

**PS**:

Note that if you put the line-edit in a layout, it will be automatically re-parented to the layout's parent. In a `QMainWindow`, this will likely be the central-widget. In that case, you should either set the attribute on the central-widget, or retrieve the main-window with `self.parent().parent()`.

Comment: Thanks! But unfortunately your last suggestion, while it makes sense, doesn't work: it says AttributeError: 'QWidget' object has no attribute 'foo'. But foo is certainly a function declared within the class MainWindow like in your example. I don't know why it doesn't find it?